# Can a Julia named parameter be required to be present?

Tags: parameters, julia, keyword-argument

In Ruby, I can require an argument both (1) appear, and (2) have a parameter name:

```
>> def f(x:)
>>   x + 1
>> end

>> f()
ArgumentError: missing keyword: x 
>> f(2)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
>> f(x:7)
=> 8
```

That is, I *have* to pass the argument, *and* I *have* to supply the associated parameter name.

I can do the same in Python:

```
>>> def f(*, x):
...   return x + 1
... 
>>> f()
TypeError: f() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'x'
>>> f(3)
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>> f(x=7)
8
```

And, for good measure, even Swift can do this:

```
1> func f(x: Int) -> Int {return x + 1}
2> f()
error: missing argument for parameter 'x' in call
2> f(3)
error: missing argument label 'x:' in call
2> f(x:7)
$R0: Int = 8
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this in **Julia**. It seems that keyword arguments, as they are called, must take default parameters. Is this correct, or is there a way to simulate the Ruby and Python examples above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Julia 0.7 and 1.x

In Julia 0.7 (which was the compatibility release with all 1.0 features), this ability was added [PR #25830](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25830).

To specify a required keyword argument list it after the `;` but do not provide a default value:

```
julia> f(; x) = x + 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(;x=3)
4

julia> f()
ERROR: UndefKeywordError: keyword argument x not assigned
```

## Julia 0.6 and earlier

This is correct.
In julia you cannot have required keyword arguments.
Key word arguments are a special type of optional argument -- one which is set by by name, rather than by position.

(Related to this: you cannot set a non-keyword argument by name -- which you can do in Python and C#.)

You can, as @amrods suggested ensure this at runtime.

I would do that with

```
function f(; x = nothing)
    x===nothing && error("x not set.")
    #...
end
```

That check will be optimized out, if they type of `x` is known (inferred) at the caller, at compile type.

but it won't actually be enforced until run-time.
You also could use @Fengyang [very elegant way to achieve the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40446356/179081)

You could probably enforce this at compile time by replacing your function with a generated function.  But it is an awful hack.

Comment: you mean `nothing`

Comment: Of course, both Python and Ruby also ensure correctness at runtime, as dynamic languages.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible in the same way as Ruby or Python. In fact, it can be as simple as

```
julia> f(x, y; z=error()) = 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1, 2)
ERROR:
 in f(::Int64, ::Int64) at ./REPL[65]:1
```

but that error message is terrible. So we can throw a better error:

```
julia> f(x, y; z=throw(ArgumentError("z is required"))) = x + y + z
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1, 2)
ERROR: ArgumentError: z is required
 in f(::Int64, ::Int64) at ./REPL[25]:1

julia> f(1, 2, z=3)
6
```

As oxinabox mentioned, the error is found at runtime instead of compile-time, but this is the same with Python or Ruby.

If this is too verbose, it's easy to make a macro:

```
macro required(ex)
    esc(Expr(:kw, ex, :(throw(ArgumentError("$($("$ex")) is required"))))
end
```

then you can do

```
julia> foo(x, y; @required(z), @required(w), n=4) = x + y + z + w + n
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(1, 2)
ERROR: ArgumentError: z is required
 in foo(::Int64, ::Int64) at ./REPL[59]:1

julia> foo(1, 2, z=3)
ERROR: ArgumentError: w is required
 in (::#kw##foo)(::Array{Any,1}, ::#foo, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./<missing>:0

julia> foo(1, 2, z=3, w=4)
14

julia> foo(1, 2, z=3, w=4, n=5)
15
```

The reason this works is that default arguments are evaluated when no argument is passed. By preventing the default argument from being successfully evaluated, this requires the user to pass an argument.

Comment: That is a very clever way to use the fact that the RHS of a default argument is evaluated if the default is not given.

Comment: Very clever indeed. So refreshing that the default is not evaluated until runtime. Was burned once long ago, as many others have been, with Python's strange rules for default arguments (esp. those mutable ones). Lovely macro BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps due to version drift, this works as you expected in `1.5.3`. Following the Swift example:

```
julia> f(;x::Int64) = x + 1

julia> f()
ERROR: UndefKeywordError: keyword argument x not assigned

julia> f(3)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64)

julia> f(x=3)
4
```

The error message in the `f(3)` case could use an improvement though.

Comment: Love it when languages evolve and improve :)

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
function f(; x = nothing)
    x + 1
end
```

Essentially you provide a default initial value.

Edit: set the default value to be `nothing`.